# Fail to use psycopg2 to pull out data from postgre database

Tags: python, postgresql

I have problem with the python PostgreSQL. I am using psycopg2.
here's my postgres DB looks like:

```
Database: qcdata
    ---information_schema
    ---pg_catalog
    ---prod
        ---activation
        --- *** Many other table ***
    ---public
```

I want to pull out the information in  schema: prod - table: activation

here's my code

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(host='10.0.80.180', port = '5432',
                    dbname = 'qcdata', 
                    user = 'username', password = 'pwd')
cur = conn.cursor()
print cur.execute("SELECT * FROM prod.activation")
```

But it returns None... I am sure there's data in it. How could that be?
Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs (http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html), the cur.execute() cursor always returns None. You have to follow up with one of the fetch methods, like:

```
print cur.fetchall()
```

-g

Answer (score 0):

While I will use cursor.fetchone() in cases where I'm getting a single value, i.e. when using `COUNT`:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM prod.activation
```

If I want to process a set of rows, I like to leverage the cursor's ability to `iterate` over the result set. That allows more control over the results, how they're processed, and how they're returned.

The cursor can be iterated over just like a Python list:

```
for row in cur:
    dostuff()
```

If you use `named cursors` (simply set the `name` attribute when constructing the cursor), `psycopg2` will chunk the `SELECT` for you, by 2000 by default. This will automatically happen in the background while iterating.

You can also use the `with` syntax to automatically close the cursor when you're done with it. (Useful for smaller-scoped uses.)